# colResizable 1.6 syncCols on demand

Tags: jquery, width, multiple-columns

I am using colResizable to implement resizable columns on a single table. The table can change the number/order of columns upon ajax request and it can also change between relative and pixel based column widths. Only some of the columns are resizable so when I use "postbackSafe" it really messes up allot of the column widths. Therefore, I am looking for a method to manually trigger the syncCols method which is usually triggered with the live drag. I have thought about manually looping through header and setting the widths manually but doing it through colResizable would position ".JColResizer" correctly as well.

Have any of you ever tried triggering the columns to synchronize manually using this plugin?